# Run node.js in git hook without blocking the terminal

Tags: node.js, git

I have the below code in githook:

```
it --work-tree=/home/aero/Services --git-dir=/home/aero/Services/.git pull
ps aux | grep node | grep services-aero | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
cd /home/aero/Services
/home/aero/.nvm/versions/node/v11.12.0/bin/node bin/server-apm-dashboard-static &> /home/aero/Services/log
```

When I push, my terminal will block while I have `&> /home/aero/Services/log` already.

I can use pm2 or forever to solve the issue, yes, but I like to know how to do it "naked."

Comment: What exactly does `bin/server-apm-dashboard-static` do? Based on the name it starts a Node server to serve static content? |

What exactly do you want to accomplish with this git hook?

Comment: Yes. I want to restart the service.

Comment: You want to restart the server when you do a `git push` ? Why? What does that solve?

Comment: Update the server.

Comment: Use a different service to start the server, that keeps checking for a file. Whenever a push happens, `touch <file>`, the first service will notice that file, restart your server, and delete the file. Ugly, but your flow is kind of weird too. In a shorter way, you can add something to crontab too, to check for this <file>, and do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a restart service hook. You should have the service started by a supervisor and then in the hook tell that supervisor to restart the service. This way it can't block the terminal as the service isn't a child of the shell.

Comment: Is it possible to start a supervisor within the post-receive file?